# Multi select plugin not selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the bootstrap `multi-select.js` for selecting multiple options from the select box. I have tried, when i click on the button multiple options not selecting. below is my code:

```js
// bootstrap multiselect box
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ddlPermission').multiselect({
    buttonWidth : '100%',
    maxHeight : 100,
    includeSelectAllOption : true,
    dropRight : true
  });  
  $(".clickbutton").click(function(){ 
   $('.multiselect').val(['A','B']);
  });  
});
function myFunction() {
  var allVal=$("#ddlPermission").val();
  alert(allVal);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<input class="form-control btn-primary clickbutton" type="button" name="select" id="select" value="Click">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<select id="ddlPermission" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="permission_ddl">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="myFunction()" class="button active" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: reorder your js lib : bootstrap multiselect should be after bootstrap and jquery

Comment: After i edit your question, looks like your code works fine, check it out.

Comment: Yes, but when i am clicking the click button A and B select, its not working

Comment: `A` and `B` selected, and after click on submit i get alert `A,B`, what do you expect?

Comment: When i am click on click button need to select options (A,B) (   $('.multiselect').val(['A','B']);)

Comment: It select A B after push the button, you mean, want to add `selected="selected" attribute to selected options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the selection to the dropdown's `id` instead of the `class` then refresh the multiselect.

```
$('#ddlPermission').val(['A','B']);
$('#ddlPermission').multiselect("refresh");
```

```js
// bootstrap multiselect box
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ddlPermission').multiselect({
    buttonWidth : '100%',
    maxHeight : 100,
    includeSelectAllOption : true,
    dropRight : true
  });  
  $(".clickbutton").click(function(){ 
   $('#ddlPermission').val(['A','B']);
        $('#ddlPermission').multiselect("refresh");
  });  
});
function myFunction() {
  var allVal=$("#ddlPermission").val();
  alert(allVal);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<input class="form-control btn-primary clickbutton" type="button" name="select" id="select" value="Click">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<select id="ddlPermission" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="permission_ddl">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="myFunction()" class="button active" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly answer. Thanks